# How can I access the Parent TabPane properties from another controller that's set for individual tabs? (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

I have an application (in Mainview.fxml, controller being mainTestController.java)that creates dynamic number of tabs based on the user input, each tab having details of an individual business entity. These details include things like ownership details, that's set up in another FXML(highlighted in red [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9pv0.jpg), for better idea), loaded each time the user focuses on a tab that's not the first tab. So I'm not able to get the tab index details in this entityInfoController class, from the mainTestController.java.

I tried this:

```
MainTestController mainObject =new MainTestController();
int currentTabIndex = mainObject.TabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

where TabPane is my

```
@FXML public TabPane TabPane; //in MainTestController.java
```

but it keeps throwing NullPointerException. I think I can try getting the tabIndex from the mainTestController directly and then passing it into the other controller class, but I feel like it's a messy/lengthy process and wondering if there's some other way to do this!

Comment: You need to access the tab pane via the actual controller. `mainObject` is not the controller. The way you suggest is the correct approach (and is only a few lines of code, depending on exactly what you are doing).

Comment: @James thanks for the information! I'll try it out.

Comment: `NullPointerException` because you create a new instance of your controller

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine A new instance of the *class that is used for the controller*. (A "controller" is a specific object. It is not a class. Referring to it as a class increases confusion in novices.)

Comment: @James_D you are right ,just i wrote in lower letters.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly